# aspnetcore 3.1 linux docker connect to sql server on windows host machine

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-web-api

My development setup are a `AspNetCore Webapi 3.1` on  `Linux docker container` (running from `Visual Studio 2019` on `Windows 10` machine name `DELL, 192.168.0.141) to connect to` SqlServerExpress 2014`.

It is successfully connect to Azure/AWS public database however it is failed with SQLSever installed on the host machine.

```
string connectionString = $"Data Source= 192.168.0.141; Initial Catalog=Db1;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Password=Password01;";

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
```

The error is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'
```

It is still failed even using `Data Source` with host machine name `DELL` as well as provide `Ip,port`.

My dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerConnectDb/DockerConnectDb.csproj", "DockerConnectDb/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerConnectDb/DockerConnectDb.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerConnectDb"
RUN dotnet build "DockerConnectDb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerConnectDb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerConnectDb.dll"]
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Accessible by running Visual Studio in Administrator mode